# In Gridview header adding image along with text

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I have a `gridview` in which I want to add an image (small up arrow or down arrow) to the header along with the text, corresponding to whether it is sorted ascending or descending.

I have searched and found some solution too. But I want an efficient solution to this problem, which may have been already known to someone here in stackoverflow. Kindly help in this regard.

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: Please go through this link http://blogfornet.com/tag/how-to-add-image-in-header-of-gridview/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by adding the correct CSS styles to your `Gridview`.

**ASP.NET Markup**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" DataSourceID="..." PageSize="5">
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle CssClass="sortasc" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle CssClass="sortdesc" />
</asp:GridView>
```

**CSS**

```
th.sortasc a  
{
    display:block; padding:0 4px 0 15px; 
    background:url(img/asc.gif) no-repeat;  
}

th.sortdesc a 
{
    display:block; padding:0 4px 0 15px; 
    background:url(img/desc.gif) no-repeat;
}
```

Reference: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scothu/archive/2010/08/28/gridview-with-sort-arrows-and-showing-header-when-empty.aspx